# how to use attribute of table in trigger body

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace trigger calculation

before insert on booking 

DECLARE name varchar2(20);

BEGIN 

IF INSERTING THEN

select first_name into name from CUSTOMER where NIC =: NEW.NIC ;

dbms_output.put_line(name);

END IF;

end;
```

Here NEW.NIC is the attribute of booking table.

it gives me following errors:

> Error: PLS-00801: internal error [ph2csql_strdef_to_diana:bind] Error:
>   PLS-00801: internal error [phdite:node kind] Error(4,1): PL/SQL: SQL
>   Statement ignored Error(4,35): PL/SQL: ORA-06544: PL/SQL: internal
>   error, arguments: [ph2csql_strdef_to_diana:bind], [], [], [], [], [],
>   [], [] Error(5,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a Row level trigger, you refer to the column using `:NEW.col`, e.g.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER calculation before
  INSERT ON booking 
  FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE 
  name VARCHAR2(20);
  BEGIN
    IF INSERTING THEN
      SELECT first_name INTO name FROM CUSTOMER WHERE NIC =:NEW.NIC ;
      dbms_output.put_line(name);
    END IF;
  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `NIC =: NEW.NIC ;`
Whereas it should be `NIC =:NEW.NIC ;`

Notice the space after `=:` is removed.